# Issue with Spinnaker automated trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cicd, aws-ecr, spinnaker

I am trying to get Spinnaker to have a pipeline use an automated trigger which is an image pushed to an ECR repo. I can add different repos fine but can't seem to see the images. I am following this guide and below is the example code I followed plus a second variation I tried.

```
ADDRESS=123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
REGION=us-west-2


hal config provider docker-registry account add my-ecr-registry \
--address $ADDRESS \
--username AWS \
--password-command "aws --region $REGION ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://'"
```

hal deploy apply
Variation I tried

```
ADDRESS=123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/api
```

Currently I can see the repo in registry name then I load the image section and nothing shows up. I have checked many times and I do have images in the repo - I've even deployed them to my kubernetes cluster and tested they work when building my helm charts.

What am I missing or can I try?

Comment: What Spinnaker version are you on? You can try looking at logs.